# Spynner -- No Module named cookielib

Tags: python-2.7, spynner

I have written the below mentioned basic script using Python Spynner.
It works fine when running through IDLE.
However, when I try to convert it into exe using Pyinstaller and run the exe, It gives me the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named cookielib
```

I have searched a lot for solution but couldn't find any. Any help would be appreciated.
I am using Python2.7 (windows 7 32 bit)

Here is the code,

```
import spynner
b=spynner.Browser()
b.hide()
b.load('http://www.google.com')
b.snapshot().save('file.png')
b.close()
```